# Async socket.send() exception

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, boto3, python-asyncio

Hello I have the following for my async loop

```
 async def start_process(restore_items, args, loop):
    with GlacierRestorer(args.temp_dir, args.error_log_bucket, loop) as restorer:
        restorer.initiate_restore_all(restore_items)

        tasks = []
        semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(4)
        for item in restore_items:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(restorer.transfer(item, semaphore)))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main():
    args = get_args()
    restore_items = get_restore_items(args)

    for item in restore_items:
        print(item.source, ':', item.destination)

    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(start_process(restore_items, args, loop))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

My job and files get larger I see that I keep getting an
socket.send() exception
After reading the documentation it seems to be coming from loop.run_until_complete

The exception doesn't come the program to crash, but eventually bogs it down so much it gets stuck printing the exception.

How do I modify the current code to fix this?

Comment: `run_until_complete` only propagates the exception raised by the `start_process` coroutine. The exception likely happens in one of the `transfer` coroutines, and `gather` dutifully reports it. If you want to ignore the exception, you can wrap `restorer.transfer` in a separate `async def that only does `try/await restorer.transfer(...)/except SocketError: pass`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I am a little confused by your response mind explaining in a snippet of code?

Comment: I've now expanded the comment to an answer that shows the code. It's incomplete because I don't understand the _cause_ of the exception, but it shows how to ignore it if that's ok in your case.

Comment: @user4815162342 Mind if i bother you again?

Comment: If you have a new issue, please consider asking a separate question. If possible, include a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run_until_complete` only propagates the exception raised inside `start_process`. This means that if an exception happens at any point during `start_process`, and `start_process` doesn't catch it, `run_until_complete(start_process())` will re-raise the same exception.

In your case the exception likely originally gets raised somewhere in `restorer.transfer()`. The call to `gather` returns the results of the coroutines, which includes raising an exception, if one occurred.

> The exception doesn't come the program to crash, but eventually bogs it down so much it gets stuck printing the exception. How do I modify the current code to fix this?

Ideally you would fix the cause of the exception - perhaps you are sending in too many requests at once, or you are using the `GlacierRestorer` API incorrectly. But some exceptions cannot be avoided, e.g. ones caused by a failing network. To ignore such exceptions, you can wrap the call to `restorer.transfer` in a separate coroutine:

```
async def safe_transfer(restorer, item, semaphore):
    try:
        return await restorer.transfer(item, semaphore)
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)  # here you can choose not to print exceptions you
                  # don't care about if doing so bogs down the program
```

In `start_process` you would call this coroutine instead of `restorer_transfer`:

```
        coros = []
        for item in restore_items:
            coros.append(safe_transfer(restorer, item, semaphore))
        await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

Note that you don't need to call `asyncio.ensure_future()` to pass a coroutine to `asyncio.gather`; it will be called automatically.