# Retry on "socket.send() raised exception"

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My code:

```
import asyncio
import time

valueTime = 3

async def telnet_client(host: str, port: int) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
            print(f"connected to ({host}, {port})")

            while True:
                writer.write("hello\n".encode())
                time.sleep(valueTime)
        except:
            print("error: inner")
try:
    asyncio.run(telnet_client("192.168.1.126", 23))
except:
    print("error: main")
```

I want to implement the following senario: When there is a communication problem, when communication is restored it will try to reconnect instead of throwing socket.send() raised exception. to infinity..

I tried add try..except but none caught the socket.send() exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [51428355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428355/async-socket-send-exception).

Comment: Did you put the `try`/`except` around your `writer.write` call? Does the stack trace show you the parent call of `socket.send()`? I think you just need to isolate where the exception happens and handle it appropriately. You may also find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779956/why-should-asyncio-streamwriter-drain-be-explicitly-called) useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way to solve this issue:**

```
import asyncio
import time  # You can remove this as we used asyncio.sleep

valueTime = 3

async def telnet_client(host: str, port: int) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
            print(f"connected to ({host}, {port})")

            while True:
                writer.write("hello\n".encode())
                await writer.drain()  # Make sure the write operation is completed
                await asyncio.sleep(valueTime)  # Used asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep which is good practice
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error: inner - {e}")
            await asyncio.sleep(valueTime)  # Wait before attempting the next connection

try:
    asyncio.run(telnet_client("192.168.1.126", 23))
except Exception as e:
    print(f"error: main - {e}")
```

Here I replaced `time.sleep` with `await asyncio.sleep` to ensure that waiting periods are non-blocking and allow the event loop to continue running other tasks. This will make sure the asynchronous nature of your application.

Next, I have added `await writer.drain()` right after sending data with `writer.write()`. This will ensure the data is sent immediately by flushing the output buffer.